# In which stage of the program do I remove my legend labels in charts.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Guys I really need your help in this matter. I tried many different variations. However, I do not come to a solution in this case. As you can see in the picture I am trying to showcase only three legend labels. However, whatever I do I am not able to get rid of even one single legend item. Only `legend:{display:false}}}` works. I do not know what else I can try out. I use the filter method in this case.

[image]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

let_25  = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78],
let_50 = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78],
let_10_90 = [40, 65, 63, 64, 72, 79, 83, 87,100,108],
let_med = [30, 40, 45, 50, 56, 60, 66, 73, 78, 85],
let_25_75 = [35, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94],
let_10 = [25, 30, 36, 39, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 68], 


myData = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8","9+"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "25th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_25,
    },{
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_10,
    },{
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_25_75,
    },{
      label:  "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_10_90,
    },
      {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: let_med,
  }]
};

// Default chart defined with type: 'line'
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "monospace";
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: myData,options: {
  legend: {
      labels: {
          filter: function(item, chart) {

           return !item.text.includes("25th Percentile");
          }
      }
  }
}})



// Function runs on chart type select update
function updateChartType() {
  // Since you can't update chart type directly in Charts JS you must destroy original chart and rebuild
  myChart.destroy();
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
  data: myData});
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class = "title">
        <h1>The GoTalent Salary Report</h1>
        <h3>Find the tech job you deserve</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <h5 class="label">Chart Type</h5>
        <select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
          <option value="line">Backend Engineer</option>
          <option value="line">Frontend Engineer</option>
          <option value="line">Fullstack Engineer</option>
          <option value="line">Mobile Engineer</option>
          <option value="line">Doughnut</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:85vw">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: To me it's not clear what labels you try to hide. According to `!item.text.includes("25th Percentile")`, you would only hide the label "25th Percentile". This however does not match what you write in your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: return !item.text.includes("25th Percentile") should pretty much do the job of removing the 25th percentile from my chart. However, it does not work so I think it has to be integrated somewhere else into my code. Do you have an idea?

Comment: more importantly, my core outcome is to remove the 25th and 10th percentile legend label. So I assume that it is not well integrated

Comment: Your `legend.labels.filter` function looks fine and it should work as expected when the chart is initially shown. The problem is that when you re-create the chart through `updateChartType`, you don't provide the `options` that include `legend.labels.filter`.

Comment: Hm, I understand...Do you have a good workaround here? I try to include legend. labels.filter into updateChartType and see whether it works out

Comment: Hm it did not work out, did actually expect that this might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your `legend.labels.filter` function looks fine and it is triggered each time the chart is created or updated.

There are however other problems in your code, Every `option` element for example has the same `value`. Therefore, each chart will look the same since `myData` either does not change.

Nevertheless, please take a look at your amended code and see how it could work.

```js
let let_25 = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78];
let let_50 = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78];
let let_10_90 = [40, 65, 63, 64, 72, 79, 83, 87, 100, 108];
let let_med = [30, 40, 45, 50, 56, 60, 66, 73, 78, 85];
let let_25_75 = [35, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94];
let let_10 = [25, 30, 36, 39, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 68];

let myData = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9+"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_25,
    }, {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_10,
    }, {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_25_75,
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
      data: let_10_90,
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: let_med,
    }
  ]
};

var myChart;
function updateChartType() {
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.destroy();
  }
  myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
    type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
    data: myData,
    options: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: item => !['25th Percentile', '10th - 90th Percentile'].includes(item.text)
        }
      }
    }
  })
};

updateChartType();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="label">Chart Type</h5>
<select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
  <option value="line">Backend Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Frontend Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Fullstack Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Mobile Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Doughnut</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:85vw">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That's interesting..When I run the code in an online editor I do not see any change..You know why this might be the case? Here it all looks fine

Answer (score 0):

whats `item` in the filter func? Is it not an instance of the data?

In which case shouldn't it be `label` and not `text`

```
return !item.label.includes("25th Percentile");
```